# Grails standalone JAR as linux service configure memory parameters

Tags: grails, service, executable-jar

I have a Grails application that I run as a Linux service. Basically I create a symlink from /etc/init.d/mygrailsservice to mygrailsservice.jar.

I want to increase the amount of OS memory allocated to the service.

How do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the spring-boot docs for executable jars and using them as system services - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Specifically https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-when-it-runs

> With the exception of JARFILE and APP_NAME, the above settings can be
>   configured using a .conf file. The file is expected next to the jar
>   file and have the same name but suffixed with .conf rather than .jar.
>   For example, a jar named /var/myapp/myapp.jar will use the
>   configuration file named /var/myapp/myapp.conf.
>
> myapp.conf.
>
> JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024M
>
> LOG_FOLDER=/custom/log/folder